# Access Violation Calling into Dynamically Loaded DLL with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker

I have a dll (C code) that is built using VS2010 and defines a set of functions. I also have an exe (C++ code), built using VS2010 that dynamically loads the dll and calls the functions. The first couple of function calls work fine then about 20% of the time a call to a third function causes an access violation at address zero. The other 80% of the time the call is fine. It's always the same function call that is causing the issue.

```
typedef void (__cdecl *mtSim_ResetODScan)(void);
mtSim_ResetODScan mpSim_ResetODScan;

if ((mpSim_ResetODScan = (mtSim_ResetODScan)GetProcAddress(mhSimDLL,
    "_Sim_ResetODScan")) == NULL) return 0;
```

At this point mpSim_ResetODScan = 0x5E9741D0. Later on the function is called and when I debug the executable it breaks execution at the function call:

```
mpSim_ResetODScan();
```

Attempting to step into the function regenerates the access violation. The VS debugger reports that mpSim_ResetODScan still has the value 0x5E9741D0.

Commenting out all code inside the function in the dll makes no difference.

In the DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl _Sim_ResetODScan(void);
```

Dependency Walker shows that the dll and exe are using MSVCR100.DLL version 10.0.30319.460.

Any suggestions on how I can debug this further or any hints on things I might have missed?

Comment: this might not have to do anything with the dll at all: the C dll might just be writing into OOB memory or so. Did you run this in debug version with all possible runtime check on?

Comment: I can't run the exe directly as it is started by another exe. The crash happens right after it starts so I can't use the "attach to process" feature in VS. The best I can do is use the JIT debugger when it has already crashed. I have all debugging features turned on.

Comment: just insert a DebugBreak() in the exe's main(), so you can attach the debugger before the crash occurrs

Comment: Is your DLL getting unloaded? Try listing loaded modules, or seeing if address 0x5E9741D0 is still valid (eg by looking at it in data window or assembly window)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program normally under debugger itself, and put a **data breakpoint** around variable `mpSim_ResetODScan` - to see when it is possibly changing. Seems to be problem of buffer overrun.

Comment: The address of the function pointer doesn't change between calling GetProcAddress and attempted execution. I verified this with the VS debugger.